# Android: html audio tag pointing to a content provider

Tags: android

I'm working with a packed web and I'm having a problem when I try to use an audio tag.

In my code I've a WebView feeded from a content provider:

wv.loadUrl("content://content_provider/web_page");

In the content provider I Override the method "openAssetFile" in order to serve the files needed by the WebView. But when I use the  tag the program never ask for the file.

I also tryed to insert the html code by using the method "loadDataWithBaseURL" where I hardcode the path using the "content://" custom protocol but it doesn't work.

It's very strange because when I use a video tag it works properly asking for the file. Any other content works properly too.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question I am posting a solution here for reference as i could not find an answer to this elsewhere.

For some reason a call to your content provider from webView (which uses the MediaPlayer) for an mp3 file does not call openAssetFile, but rather it calls openFile. (not sure if the provider handles this routing). This problem appears to have been fixed in 4.2+

The solution for older versions which worked for me was to override openFile in your content provider thus:

```
@Override
public AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFile(Uri uri, String mode){
    //your asset reading code that works for other file types here.
}
@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode){
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = openAssetFile(uri, mode);
        return afd.getParcelFileDescriptor();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This works for me on Android 4.04 & 4.1